# Bootstrap columns within columns for iteration over an object

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, multiple-columns

I want to create a pair of bootstrap columns inside another bootstrap column.

My output is not as desired for some reason.They look completely goofy for some reason. Did I make a rookie mistake in my formatting?

I am iterating over a @user object and having the profile picture be on the left and the profile info be on the right. There are many users so it should ideally style for all the iterations of the users in the database.

I feel this code should work but it doesn't, any idea as to what happened:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="other-box col-sm-6">
        <p>Random text!!!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="index-user-container col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <% @users.each do |user| %>
                <div class="index-picture col-sm-4">
                    <%= image_tag user.image.thumb('150x185#').url if user.image_stored? %>
                </div>
                <div class="index-info-box col-sm-8">
                    <%= user.first_name %>
                    <%= user.last_name %>
                    <%= user.email %>
                    <%= link_to 'Go to profile', user_path(@user) %>
                </div>    
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I am using twitter bootstrap. Here is a screen shot of the goofyness:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a new row for each user in the list, then put the iterator above the row div, not inside it - otherwise, you might get some funky results.

```
<div class="index-user-container col-sm-6">
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <div class="row">
            <div class="index-picture col-sm-4">
                <%= image_tag user.image.thumb('150x185#').url if user.image_stored? %>
            </div>
            <div class="index-info-box col-sm-8">
                <%= user.first_name %>
                <%= user.last_name %>
                <%= user.email %>
                <%= link_to 'Go to profile', user_path(@user) %>
            </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Think about Bootstrap's gridding system like Microsoft Excel, whereby you have rows (horizontal) and columns (vertical), which you can fill with data. In your case, you'd like a new row for each user. And each row will contain 2 columns, one for the image and one for the user info, like name and email. In your previous code, you were creating just ONE row, and adding many, many columns (essentially 2 columns for every user, but only in one row). So if we move the iterator ABOVE the row creation, we will always get a new row for each user. Make sense?